# PHP: Wildcards on multidimensional key

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array `$array["A"]["B"]["C"]["D"]`. The list is longer.
Is there a wildcard that I can use to get ["D"] value in let say ["B"] array?
Something like this, `$array["A"]["B"][*]["D"]` ?
or `$array[*]["B"][*]["D"]` ?

Example, I would like to get all prices that were bought on February regardless of the year.

```
$array[2013][2][23]["ItemName"]["ItemPrice"] .....
```

If this would work, it would be really wonderful

```
$array[*][2][*][*]["ItemPrice"]..
```

any idea?

Comment: this is not possible. you'll have to loop on every layer of array and search for your value.

Comment: If you find yourself in this situation, you usually want to backtrack to where the data is retrieved (SQL) and retrieve what you want more specifically.

Comment: There are programming languages that offer this functionality, such as R and Python (using NumPy), but PHP does not.

Comment: @DigitalChris the data is from excel, I was trying to sort it out in new array. re-reading the file will have to use a lot of memory.

Answer (score 1):

You could do multiple `foreach` to loop though every nested array that you want to loop though.

```
foreach ($array as $a) {
    foreach ($a["B"] as $c) {
        foreach ($c as $d) {
           // Do something with $d
        }
    }
}
```

This would be `$array[*]["B"][*][*]`

**Edit:** You could combine my suggestion with a `while` loop.

```
$innerArray = $array;
while (true) {
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        if ($key == "D") {
            // Do something with this value
        } else if (is_array($value)) { 
            $innerArray = $value; 
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the array dimension is long and some data need to reference to b, some need to reference to c. and the length of the dimension is not known to create foreach.

Comment: I don't really know how to post the solution here as it is quiet complicated. But this shed some light. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Sepehr-Farshid it just crossed my mind that I can use recursive function (Something that I haven't use for quiet a while. So here a example.

```
$newarray = array();
$tempArray = $oldarray;

$levels[] = 1;
$keys[] = 2;
$levels[] = 4;
$keys[] = "ItemPrice";
$lastLevel =4;

recurArray($tempArray, 0);

function recurArray($array, $level)
{
   foreach($array as $key => $value) {
     if(array_search($level, $GLOBALS["levels"]) {
       $tempKey = array_search($level, $GLOBALS["levels"];
       if($key == $GLOBALS["keys"][$tempKey] {
         if($level == $GLOBALS["lastLevel"]) $GLOBALS["newarray"] = $value;
         else recurArray($value, $level + 1);
       }
       else { return; }          
     }
     else { recurArray($value, $level + 1); }
   }  
}
```

this might not be the optimum way, but it will work and can be refined. :D